# Outlook 2016 unable to connect to or sync with Outlook.com EAS - client has Access State of quarantined

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016, outlook.com, activesync

Got a bit of a problem that I have been able to replicate not only on a client’s machine, but also on my own with my own credentials.

- Outlook 2016 x64, Office 2016 Professional Plus
- Windows 10 Pro x64
- Dual Intel Xeon x5960, 12 cores 24 threads
- 64Gb PC3L-12800R (4x 16Gb RDIMMs)
- [user]@outlook.com eMail account (mine)
- [user]@live.ca eMail account (client’s)
- eas.outlook.com or m.outlook.com server; m.hotmail.com fails explicitly

When I go to set up the account *fresh* (no prior setup), I use the Outlook.com EAS configuration to set up the account. Everything goes well, am able to connect through the account connection tester (the password is good), but when I actually open up Outlook 2016 I am presented with the list of Outlook.com account folders on the left and a single eMail in the inbox that talks about “[Reconnect Outlook 2016/Outlook 2013 to Outlook.com to resume email access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Reconnect-Outlook-2016-or-Outlook-2013-to-Outlook-com-for-uninterrupted-email-access-cda1751d-9503-40bf-bf76-e79454ac5eb3?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA)”. Problem is, this is a fresh setup (on the computer itself). Technically I *am* doing a reconnection!

When I go into the Outlook.com web account (for either account), and go [Gear] -> Options -> General -> Mobile Devices, I can see the desktop client in the list of mobile devices (??). When I click on it and then on the pencil icon (properties?) I get a popup sidebar that shows the details. It is clearly the desktop program, as the User-Agent is showing the full desktop client string: `Outlook/16.0 (16.0.6965.6570; C2R; x64)`. Right below it, it shows the Access State as being Quarantined, and below that, the Access Set By as being blank (null).

I am at a loss as to how to correct this issue. Looking for help in this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, Microsoft stopped using EAS for Outlook.com accounts. Currently Outlook.com is just an Exchange Server Online.

So: stop using Exchange ActiveSync, as it is no longer provided. Switch to full Exchange Server Online connectivity. This requires you to delete and rebuild your connection settings.

Comment: And yet, they say nothing about this anywhere. Not in the auto-email that ends up being the only thing in your inbox, nor in publicly available instructions for setting up Outlook (nearly all of which still include the EAS setup instructions for Outlook.com). They just say that Outlook needs to be “reconnected”, which IMHO is probably the most useless piece of information possible if the instructions don’t correct the assumption that the setup is the same as previously. /rant

Comment: FYI, thank you. Fixed the problem in under 2 minutes once I had that little gem of information.

Comment: @RenéKåbis and thims: does my edit describe what you need to do to fix this? (Most visitors cannot see René's earlier comment to a deleted answer.) If not, please edit. Thanks.